# Extract first ocurrence of an item in column A based on column B using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data, and I would like to create a result set that includes the rows that are the change in `Item` and the first ocurrence of `Code == 1`. Note that the first `Code` seen after a chnage in `Item` does not always have to be 1 (see the *):

The input data:

```
 DateTime                Item   Code
*2016-12-02 16:34:00     1      1 
 2016-12-02 16:35:00     1      4
 2016-12-02 16:36:00     1      1
 2016-12-02 16:37:00     1      1
 2016-12-02 16:38:00     1      7
 2016-12-02 16:39:00     1      5
 2016-12-02 16:40:00     1      6
 2016-12-02 16:41:00     2      5
*2016-12-02 16:42:00     2      1
 2016-12-02 16:43:00     2      4
 2016-12-02 16:44:00     2      1
 2016-12-02 16:45:00     2      5
 2016-12-02 16:46:00     2      8
 2016-12-02 16:47:00     2      1
 2016-12-02 16:48:00     5      7
 2016-12-02 16:49:00     5      7
*2016-12-02 16:50:00     5      1
 2016-12-02 16:51:00     5      1
 2016-12-02 16:52:00     5      4
 2016-12-02 16:53:00     5      3
*2016-12-02 16:54:00     1      1
 2016-12-02 16:55:00     1      1
 2016-12-02 16:56:00     1      1
 2016-12-02 16:57:00     1      8
 2016-12-02 16:58:00     1      9
 2016-12-02 16:59:00     1      3
 2016-12-02 17:00:00     1      2
 2016-12-02 17:01:00     1      4
```

Expected output data:

```
 DateTime                Item   Code
*2016-12-02 16:34:00     1      1 
*2016-12-02 16:42:00     2      1
*2016-12-02 16:50:00     5      1
*2016-12-02 16:54:00     1      1
```

I am using SQL Server 2012 Express. If anyone has recommendations of a good reference to learn these things, that would be great too.

Comment: Is code = 1 significant or is it just a fluke they are all 1 in your expected output?

Comment: No Keith, the Code == 1 is significant and I will always be looking for that code to signify the start of a record, since the first instance of Code == 1 for a new change in Item signifies a new record to be processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use difference of `ROW_NUMBER`s to get the determine where the value of `Item` has changed and then another `ROW_NUMBER` from that to get the first occurrence of `Code = 1`:

```
WITH CteGrp AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Datetime) -
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Datetime)
    FROM #Tbl
),
Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item, grp ORDER BY Code, Datetime)
    FROM CteGrp
)
SELECT
    Datetime, Item, Code
FROM Cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Datetime;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/591187)</kbd>

---

The first CTE is a common solution to Grouping Islands of Contiguous Dates. Here is an article by Jeff Moden for explanation:

- [Group Islands of Contiguous Dates (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/)

Comment: you might include date in the second cte for row number calculation.

Comment: @vkp, you mean add `DateTime` in the `ORDER BY` after `Code`?

Comment: I should have mentioned that the first code encountered after a change in item might not be a 1 - I will ammend te data to illustrate that fact.

Comment: Thanks. I will deconstruct and check what each bit is doing and get back to you.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the code would not work if I wanted to detected Code == 4 instead of Code == 1 ?

Comment: Yes it will not. You can always put a `WHERE` clause in the second `Cte`.

Comment: The code works as required Felix, but I am having a little difficulty in understanding why - any chance you could give me a few lines of insight into how it is working?

Comment: @beliskna Please see updated answer with a link to an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        [DateTime]
        , Item
        , Code
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY [DateTime]) AS RowNum
)
SELECT
    [DateTime]
    , Item
    , Code
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
    AND Code = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select min( dateTime) dateTime, item, code from (
    select dateTime, item, code from theTableName where code = 1
) code_1s
group by item, code
```

EDIT

To get every instance of an item where a new sequence has started .. and code = 1 is the flag for the new sequence instance ... it is a simple select statement with a where clause.

```
 select dateTime, item, code from theTableName where code = 1
```

Comment: Keith, I think that only selects the first instance of code for every instance of item - but item repeats many times in the database - for example, item 6 will be repeated say 20 times at different times of the month and what I would like is to generate a result set row every time a new instance of item 6 is encountered, not just the first time.

Comment: I'm sorry Keith, maybe I'm not explaining myself well. I need to find the first occurrence of Code == 1 within every instance of Item - so when Item changes I need a results row that shows the first occurrence of Code == 1, when Item changes again I need to show the first occurrence of Code == 1 and so on and so on for each change in Item.

Comment: Yes. I have tested it and it is working well. I didn't know if you were going down a different rout, Keith which is why I was coming back to you, but I'm very grateful for your input regardless. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Have a read through Joe Celko's Thinking in Sets. That will help you a great deal when working with SQL. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=thinking+in+sets+Joe+Celko&oq=thinking+in+sets+Joe+Celko&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.662j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Cheers, Keith. I will check it out.